# Linked lists - single or double pointer to the head

Tags: c, linked-list

We are given a task and a struct of linked list:

```
typedef struct dlistint_s
{
    int n;
    struct dlistint_s *prev;
    struct dlistint_s *next;
} dlistint_t;
```

And the function with the following prototype:

```
dlistint_t *add_dnodeint(dlistint_t **head, const int n);
```

What are the advantages and why one would be using a double pointer to the head when creating a function?

Comment: I would advise against this design. It's better to have a "list" struct with pointers to the first and last "node". This lets you modify the list by passing it in, rather than working with the nodes directly

Comment: Normally, you'd use either `bool add_dnodeint(dlistint_t **head, int n)` with a pointer to pointer argument and a non-pointer return value (or no return value — `void`), or `dlistint_t *add_nodeint(dlistint_t *head, int n)` with a simple pointer argument and a matching pointer return value (used as `head = add_nodeint(head, newval);`).  You would not normally do both at once — use a pointer to pointer argument and return a pointer value.  Note that the `const int n` is pretty much pointless because `n` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

The reason to pass pointer to pointer to `head` is that any modification to the pointer `head` will be seen in the caller function and you do not have to return head from your function.

For example, consider this simple node:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

A function to add a node to the list at front

```
struct Node *add_node (struct Node *list, int n){
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(new_node == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->data = n;
    new_node->next = list;
    return new_node;
}
```

If we need to assign the `new_node` to the `list` instead of returning it then we need to modify the above function and remove the return statement and put a statement

```
list = new_node;
```

But, **that will not work!**
This is because in C, like all arguments, pointers are passed by value.
That means the `list` contains the copy of the pointer value passed to `add_node` function and not the pointer passed to this function itself.
That's where we need pointer to pointer.

```
void add_node (struct Node **list, int n){
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(new_node == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->data = n;
    new_node->next = *list;
    *list = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a double pointer, you can pass in the address of the head so your functions can modify the actual pointer. This way you don't need to return the new head.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you are using `dlistint_t *head` variable instead of using `dlistint_t **head` variable in function parameter then, changes made in variable `head` in function `dlistint_t *add_dnodeint(dlistint_t **head, const int n);` will be local to this method. Since you are using `Node*` so changes done in variable `head` is local to that function. If you want to reflect these changes even after function call(which you obviously wants to) then use `dlistint_t **head`.